Excel spreadsheet with multi-select column and data validation
I am creating an Excel spreadsheet with 3 columns: category, subcategory and description.
Category and subcategory will both have dropdowns. I have already added this by using name ranges and data validation. Subcategory selects the correct name range based on the input of the category in the cell to its left. However, I have just added multiselect in these drop downs by following this tutorial and using this code snippet. I did slightly alter it so that the delimiter is a ;.
Now the subcategory does not populate. Currently it is because the data validation uses this formula =INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2, ",", ""), " ", "_"), "/", "_"))
which parses the string input in the cell to its left, removing any commas and replacing spaces and / with an _.
I need to change this formula so that it can split a string by ';' and then somehow concatenate the different lists corresponding to the name ranges.
The description column uses a lookup formula =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E2, Sheet2!B:C, 2, FALSE), "")
I will also need to change this so that it also splits the subcategory string by ; and concatenates each respective description.
Any advice on how to do these 3 steps would be much appreciated.

So you have a multi-select on Category AND Subcategory?

Yes correct. Multi-select on category will allow you to select subcategories from different lists. And selecting multiple sub-categories should concatenate the descriptions together.

Separate subcategory string by ';' and concatenate the corresponding lists:
To split subcategory string based on ';' delimiter use the TEXTSPLIT function. This will allow you to separate a string into multiple parts based on specific delimiters
=TEXTSPLIT(A2, {";"})
In this case, cell A2 contains the subcategory string. The TEXTSPLIT function will split the string into an array of values, and then you can concatenate these values
to concatenate the descriptions corresponding to the subcategories use the VLOOKUP function to look up the corresponding descriptions in Sheet2. if the separate subcategories are in column B and the descriptions are in column C of Sheet2 use the formula in the descriptions column of your current sheet
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E2, Sheet2!B:C, 2, FALSE), "")
This will search for the subcategory (which is in cell E2) in column B of Sheet2 and return the corresponding description from column C. If it doesn't find a match, it will return an empty string ("").
to update the data validation formula for the subcategory adjust the data validation formula for the subcategory. Instead of using the original formula, use the separate subcategory array you made earlier. If the separate subcategories are in column F, use this formula for data validation in cell D2:
=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F2, ",", ""), " ", ""), "/", ""))
This will take the selected subcategory (which is now in cell F2) and search for the corresponding name range.

I'm struggling to follow but thanks for the tip about using textsplit. I got this to work using some VBA code and textsplit.
